# Factory For Generic Parameter Object Handler

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, polymorphism, factory, factory-pattern

I have an API involving several behaviorless parameter objects that each have their own handler:

```
//some POCOs
public class CustomerChange : IChange{

    public int CustomerId {get;set;}

    public DateTime TimeStamp {get;set;}

}

public class SomeOtherChange : IChange{

    public int AParameter {get;set;}

    public string AnotherParameter {get;set;}

    public DateTime TimeStamp {get;set;}

}

// stateless handlers that will be resolve with a DI container (Ninject in my case)
public interface IChangeHandler<TChange>{
     public Handle(T change);
}

public class CustomerChangeHandler : IChangeHandler<CustomerChange>{

     private readonly ICustomerRepository customerRepository;

     public  CustomerChangeHandler(ICustomerRepository repo){
          customerRepository = repo;
     }

     public Handle(CustomerChange change){

           customerRepository.DoStuff(change.CustomerId);

     }
}
```

and so on.

This works great when the Type of IChange is known at compile time, however, I'm running into a situation where I need to handle IChanges of an unknown type.

In an ideal world I would like to be able to do something like:

```
public class ChangeHandlerFactory {

   public void HandleChange(IChange change){
        // get the change handler from the DI container based on the concrete type of IChange
        var handlerType = typeof(IChangeHandler<>)
            .MakeGenericType(change.GetType());

        object handler = container.GetInstance(handlerType);  //is this an acceptable way to use a DI container?  I would need a dependency on IKernel in this case

        handler.Handle(change);  // I would need to cast the change object to the appropriate type for the handler or make handler dynamic which seems like it has the potential for hard to debug issues
   }


}
```

My concern with having handler as a dynamic is the potential for someone to do something incorrectly and getting a tricky to debug error.

I could have each POCO implement a GetHandler method that retrieves the handler but this pretty much defeats the whole point of separating them in the first place.

What would be the best way to get the handler in a situation like this?  Is there a way to do it without using my DI container (ninject) as a service locator and/or without using dynamics?  I've found that I've run into this situation a number of times, but haven't yet come up with a solution that feels right.

Comment: *This works great when the Type of IChange is known at runtime, however, I'm running into a situation where I need to handle IChanges of an unknown type at runtime*  Did you mean *compile time?* If you can't tell what type something is at runtime there is something really wrong happening :D

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is dependency inversion. Have the POCO provide a delegate for getting its own handler, since it obviously already knows what type it is.

```
interface IChange
{
    IChangeHandler GetHandler(Container container);
}

public class SomeOtherChange : IChange
{
    public int AParameter {get;set;}

    public string AnotherParameter {get;set;}

    public DateTime TimeStamp {get;set;}

    public IChangeHandler GetHandler(Container container) => container.GetInstance<SomeOtherChangeHandler>();

}
```

Then you can write a generic handler mapper:

```
public void HandleChange(IChange change)
{
    var handler = change.GetHandler(container);
    //etc....
```

Of course that leaves you with the question of what to do with the handler once you have it. Again, you can let the POCO do the work:

```
public class SomeOtherChange : IChange
{
    public int AParameter {get;set;}

    public string AnotherParameter {get;set;}

    public DateTime TimeStamp {get;set;}

    public void GetAndCallHandler(Container container)
    {
        var handler = container.GetInstance<SomeOtherChangeHandler>();
        handler.Handle(this);
    }
}
```